# Python - addition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a program that adds the input, which will be in the form of '7 5 4 1' etc with a space between each number, and will add 7, 5, 4 and 1 for the output. So far I've got nothing working.

```
x = []
inp = int(input('Enter the expenses: '))
x.extend(inp.split())
print((sum)(x))
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to convert the input to integers *after* splitting:

```
inp = input('Enter the expenses: ')
numbers = [int(i) for i in inp.split()]
print(sum(numbers))
```

Comment: You might want to use `raw_input` and sum up `numbers` instead of `inp` :)

Comment: Getting the error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: @Thibault: This is Python 3, there is no `raw_input()`. Fair point about the variable mix-up, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

```
print(sum([int(x) for x in inp.split()]))
```

sum - sumarize int/float list
[function(x) for x in list] - a python list comprehensions (a common and nice structure)
int() - convert string to integer
inp.split() - split a string into a list of strings

Explanation from inside to outside: you split the string into a list of strings, convert every string into integer-numbers and summarize it.